# SQL Query on using join command and union

Tags: sql

`code` prints a table with columns `play ID`, `play title`, `play year` which has values in the table ordered by  play year

I want to add Drama, Comedy, Tragedy tables into as ONE column in the huge table.

So the table should print like this with values below each column:

`P_NO`, `P_TITLE`, `P_YEAR`, `TYPE`

TYPE is

```
select d.D_TYPE as "TYPE" from DRAMA d where d.D_P_NO=p.P_NO   
UNION
select c.C_TYPE as "TYPE" from COMEDY c where c.C_P_NO=p.P_NO  
UNION    
select t.T_TYPE as "TYPE" from TRAGEDY t where t.T_P_NO=p.P_NO
```

So my question is how can I add the table TYPE into the below code where the `SYNTAX is CORRECT` and works because my above declaration is wrong and does not work with JOIN tables

code:

```
  select p.P_NO, cast(p.P_TITLE as varchar(15)) as P_TITLE, p.P_YEAR 
  from PLAY p 
  order by p.P_YEAR
```

Comment: What are the column structures of DRAMA, COMEDY, and TRAGEDY. Why are they not in a PlayType table that the Play table references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be You are looking for this

```
select p.P_NO, 
cast(p.P_TITLE as varchar(15)) as P_TITLE, 
p.P_YEAR ,
      (select d.D_TYPE as "TYPE" 
            from DRAMA d 
            where d.D_P_NO=p.P_NO  
      UNION
       select c.C_TYPE as "TYPE" 
            from COMEDY c 
            where c.C_P_NO=p.P_NO  
      UNION    
       select t.T_TYPE as "TYPE" 
            from TRAGEDY t 
            where t.T_P_NO=p.P_NO 
      ) as TYPE
from PLAY p 
order by p.P_YEAR
```